# Best disk perfomance in VMWare Fusion: VMDisk or Bootcamp partition ?

Tags: macos, boot-camp, vmware-fusion

I need to run Windows and MacOS alongside each other on my Macbook Pro. I have VMWare Fusion.

For best performance, should i choose to install a Bootcamp partition and run that through VMWare Fusion, or should I use a virtual disk with Fusion ? Answers linking to actual performance benchmarks between the two options with recent hardware and software versions, is an extra plus.

I know that the Bootcamp partition has the added benefit that I can boot into Windows only, but I am not likely to use that feature a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this on Twitter to the @VMWareFusion account and got the following reply:

> run on a virtual disk for best disk performance.

https://twitter.com/VMwareFusion/status/427963892963487744

Comment: I'll accept my own answer here, since I haven't gotten any other ones. I did install Windows on a Virtual disk, and it performs well.